# Example of computing value of risk function of decision rule

Tags: decision-theory

Risk function is defined as

$$R(\theta, \delta) := \int L(\theta, \delta(x)) P_{\theta}(dx)$$

where $x = (x_1, ... x_n)$ is an observation and $\delta(x)$ is a decision rule.

$P_{\theta}(x) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}})^n exp (\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{-(x_i-\theta)^2}{2}),$
$L(\theta, \delta) = (\theta - \delta)^2$ and $\delta(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}$.

1. Is $\delta(x)$ a proper example of decision rule?
2. Assuming that it is, how to calculate the value of $R$? I don't fully understant the notation and never seen an example, just theoretical definitions. (If answer to (1) is "no", can you provide an example of proper decision rule and then show how to calculate $R$?

Comment: you should probably state your definition of 'proper' decision rule. Your other definitions could also be made more complete, what do you mean $\delta(x) = 1/n\sum x$? Is x vector valued?

Comment: Yes, $x = (x_1, ... x_n), x_i \in R$. Maybe I don't understand definition of decision rule. I know that it's a function $\delta: X \rightarrow U$ where $X$ - space of observations, $U$ - set of "actions". Here action is value of estimator of $\theta$, which is the sample mean.

Comment: Well if $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ then your probability distribution is ill-specified. .

Comment: @BranBar sorry, $P_\theta(x)$ should be joint distribution function. I edited the question.